# Splitting Routes File Into Multiple Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm working w/ a Rails 3 application and I want to split up the routes into separate files depending on the subdomain. Right now I have this in my routes.rb file:

```
Skateparks::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:subdomain => 'api') do
    load 'routes/api.rb'
  end
end
```

And In my routes/api.rb file I have:

```
resources :skateparks
```

This doesn't seem to work though because if I run `rake routes` I get

```
undefined method `resources' for main:Object
```

Also, if I try to navigate to http://0.0.0.0:3000/ I get:

***Routing Error***

```
No route matches "/"
```

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 3.2, config.paths is now a hash, so @sunkencity's solution can be modified to:

```
# config/application.rb
config.paths["config/routes"] << File.join(Rails.root, "config/routes/fooroutes.rb")
```

Comment: Thanks! We have multiple files in that dir; this worked fine: `config.paths["config/routes"] += Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")]`

Comment: And if you tack on a `Dir[…].sort` I believe you can rely on that ordering.

Answer (score 4):

Sunkencity's answer seems to be identical to the following link, but for completeness' sake: https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2011/05/04/split-route-namespaces-into-different-files/

Note that routes defined later will override routes defined earlier. However, if you use something like

```
    config.paths.config.routes.concat(
        Dir[Rails.root.join('config/routes/*.rb')])
```

you don't know in what order the files will be read. So use

```
    config.paths.config.routes.concat(
        Dir[Rails.root.join('config/routes/*.rb')].sort)
```

instead, so you at least know they will be in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Add the route file to the app route loading path:

```
# config/application.rb
config.paths.config.routes << File.join(Rails.root, "config/routes/fooroutes.rb")
```

Wrap your other route file in a block like this.

```
#config/routes/fooroutes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do |map|
  match 'FOO' => 'foo/bar'
end
```

Works for me in rails 3.0

Comment: Removed the suggestion for engines, and added config routes. should work!

Comment: I get the error `undefined method `config' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fc3fdd1e7a0` using the config.paths.config.routes

Comment: i too got the same. any body knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Doesn't work with Rails 3.2, but see [Sam Gibson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248817/6962).

Answer (score 0):

We used this in our app:

```
    config.paths['config/routes'] = Dir["config/routes/*.rb"]
```

If you try to access `config.paths['config/routes']` normally, it returns the relative path to `config/routes.rb`, so by doing the above you're giving it relative paths to all of the files in your routes folder and removing the reference to `config/routes.rb`