# rails 4: split routes.rb into multiple smaller files

Tags: split, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to split my routes in rails 4 application. For rails 3 the question has been answered a few times like:

- [How to split routes.rb into smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907398/how-to-split-routes-rb-into-smaller-files)
- [Splitting Routes File Into Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303660/splitting-routes-file-into-multiple-files)

***What would be the correct way to do this in rails 4 + how to get control over the order the routes get loaded?***

Suggested from the rails 3 questions:

**application.rb**

```
    config.paths['config/routes'] = Dir["config/routes/*.rb"]
```

Fails with:

> /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@books/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in
>   `rescue in execute_if_updated':
>   Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to
>   updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil:
>
> @route_sets=[#]>
>   (RuntimeError)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was removed from Rails 4 in June of 2012. [5e7d6bba](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5e7d6bba79393de0279917f93b82f3b7b176f4b5) reverts an earlier commit, removing support for loading multiple external route files as part of config.rb.

For further read, check out the comments on this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/fa736e69a197...2d9dbf416b14).

Answer (score 21):

I've manage that this way:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('config/routes')

# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'

  extend ApiRoutes
end

# config/routes/api_routes.rb
module ApiRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      namespace :api do
        resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here I added `config/routes` directory to autoload modules defined in it.
This will ensure that routes are reloaded when these files change.

Use `extend` to include these modules into the main file (they will be autoloaded, no need to require them).

Use `instance_exec` inside `self.extended` to draw routes in the context of router.

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to the party but you can do this in Rails 4 by monkey patching the mapper at the top of your routes.rb file. ie:

```
# config/routes.rb
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def draw(routes_name)
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/routes/#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
end
```

And then using the `draw` method in routes.rb with:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  draw :api
end
```

This will expect a file in config/routes/api.rb.

A slightly fuller explanation with [examples of splitting the routes file](https://www.michaelcho.me/article/how-to-split-rails-routesrb-into-multiple-smaller-files) here.

Comment: You recommended monkey patching without warning about the bad things that monkey patching might do to a project.

Comment: @yagooar, I'm using this in my project, what is exactly wrong with it? Quick google search didn't provide any 'bad' things

Comment: I guess this should brake routes reloading

Answer (score 1):

I don't like previously posted solutions - extensions through monkey-patching aside - since they either:

1. break OOP (`File.read` + `instance_eval` - cripes) or
2. inhibit reusability: including modules - you can do it only once - never mind that on the 2nd you understand that module inclusion is actually a mechanic to execute a bit of code, cripes

we're not in the 2000s any more, it shouldn't be acceptable to move parts of source files around and `File.read`-`instance_eval` them and then wonder what happened - or include modules as a poor man's function call - if there's any alternative.

I do this, notice it is nestable:

```
scope :processing do
  SomeModule::SomeDomain::Routes.call(self)
end

# and it's reusable:
scope :some_other_scope do
  SomeModule::SomeDomain::Routes.call(self)
end
```

The benefit of this approach is that in the end it's just simple executable ruby code that can be moved around and understood clearly both by your IDE and by your fellow programmers.

You will find the above-mentioned piece of code in `routes.rb` you will look at it, you will control-click it [and what you'll find is what you expected](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35l-OFlmGWs):

```
module SomeModule::SomeDomain
  class Routes
    def self.call r
      r.scope :some_scope do
        r.match .....
    end
  end
end
```

this means this is clean code.

It's also not stuck in "function-oriented code organization" that rails seemingly enforces for a long time now, but allows you to build domain-specific structures with their own route trees that should be the preferable norm.

PS

I also use a [module](https://github.com/info-sig/infosig-utils/blob/master/lib/common/class_functional.rb) that makes a class quack like a function - allows composition with procs and much more - but this isn't really necessary here, it'd just give you the syntax candy of saying `SomeModule::SomeDomain::Routes[self]`