# Refactoring a large routes.rb file in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in the process of upgrading a rails 3 app to rails 4.0.1.

In my rails 3 app I have the following code in the my `application.rb` to use multiple route files.

> config.paths["config/routes"] += Dir[Rails.root.join('config',
>   'routes', '*.rb').to_s]

but that throws an exception when I try to use the same thing in rails 4.

Any tips?

Comment: can you post the exception in your question ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In one of my larger applications I use the following segment of code inside of my **config/routes.rb** file.

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def draw(routes_name)
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/routes/#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
end

YourApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  # Loads config/routes/common.rb
  draw :common
  # Loads config/routes/another.rb
  draw :another
end
```

---

Rails 4 initially had support for `draw :routeName` but it was **removed** as it did not show any improvements.  *(I dont know ^.^)* You can check out the git commit doing so here: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5e7d6bba79393de0279917f93b82f3b7b176f4b5

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for sharing. I can't get changes in the config/routes/x.rb files to be picked up by the autoloader. Did you ever get a solution for that?

Comment: Last time I checked (around a year ago), there was no solution for getting those routes to autoload.  Just have to quickly restart the rails server.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this SO answer: [rails 4: split routes.rb into multiple smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844813/rails-4-split-routes-rb-into-multiple-smaller-files)

Looks like this ability was deprecated in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big your application is. But you should look into [routing concern](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) in rails 4, if you need some proper refactoring with Rails route.

**Mo' files, mo' problems.**

Comment: I typically agree with the statement `mo files, mo problems`, but for the application i was personally working on, the one application was divided into 4-5 modules where different teams of developers were working on different modules.  It made it simpler to provide each module with its own route file, and then put the common / all encompassing routes in the main routes.rb file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I have fairly separate modules that can't be refactored into concerns. I'll keep that in mind as the app continues to grow.

Comment: if your application is that big, you can think about refactoring to engines.

Comment: If more files means more problems you have an organization issue.