# Ruby On Rails Overlapping Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm rebuilding/redesigning a site in Rails that's currently in production using Magento. To ensure that I don't lower my seo rankings I am keeping my URI's the same. I am facing an optimization issue with this because the current site doesn't have subdirectories. With that said, the products are under the root directory of the site, the reviews are under the root directory of the site, and all the other content pages are under the root directory of the site. 
for example a product might be at

```
www.example.com/some-product-name
```

and a review could be at

```
www.example.com/some-review-name
```

rails obviously uses routes and my first guess was to make a route that looks like this:

```
get '/:uri_identifier', to: 'pages#find_page'
```

This works fine, but with 50k products to query through and 5k reviews along with another 200 different content pages, this creates an optimization issue since this controller method becomes a catch all to figure out which page it should render based on

```
params[:uri_identifier]
```

The uri's don't have any kind of form either so filtering them with an if statement to avoid large amounts of queries isn't really feasible. My idea was to create routes specific for the reviews and add them in routes.erb above the route

```
get '/:uri_identifier', to: 'pages#find_page'
```

but I'm still going to have to create close to 5k routes to pull this off. I did try this and it worked, but I'm not real sure what is the best way to approach this issue to ensure that I use the least amount of resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are several patterns for solving this kind of problems in rails. One of which is slug constraint. Use this resources they help with the concept of using slugs and refactoring large rails routes

1. http://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app/
2. http://code-worrier.com/blog/custom-slugs-in-rails/
3. [Refactoring a large routes.rb file in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781163/refactoring-a-large-routes-rb-file-in-rails-4)