# Divide large routes.rb to multiple files in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upgrade my rails 4 app to 5.0.0.beta2. Currently I divided the `routes.rb` file to multiple files by setting `config.paths["config/routes.rb"]` e.g.,

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.paths["config/routes.rb"]
      .concat(Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")])
  end
end
```

It seems rails 5.0.0.beta2 also exposes `config.paths["config/routes.rb"]` but the above code doesn't work. How can I divide `routes.rb` file in rails 5?

Comment: [Check out this answer, works on any Rails afaik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484075/1983072)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Rails 6.1+ built-in way to load routes from multiple files.

[From official Rails docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#breaking-up-very-large-route-file-into-multiple-small-ones):

---

#### Breaking up very large route file into multiple small ones:

If you work in a large application with thousands of routes, a single `config/routes.rb` file can become cumbersome and hard to read.

Rails offers a way to break a gigantic single `routes.rb` file into multiple small ones using the draw macro.

```rb
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'foo', to: 'foo#bar'

  draw(:admin) # Will load another route file located in `config/routes/admin.rb`
end

# config/routes/admin.rb

namespace :admin do
  resources :comments
end
```

Calling `draw(:admin)` inside the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block itself will try to load a route file that has the same name as the argument given (`admin.rb` in this case). The file needs to be located inside the `config/routes` directory or any sub-directory (i.e. `config/routes/admin.rb` or `config/routes/external/admin.rb`).

You can use the normal routing DSL inside the `admin.rb` routing file, however you shouldn't surround it with the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block like you did in the main `config/routes.rb` file.

---

[Link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37892).

Comment: Cool, I'll migrate to the official way after 6.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

you can write some codes in config/application.rb

```
config.paths['config/routes.rb'] = Dir[Rails.root.join('config/routes/*.rb')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution also auto reloads the routes on code change. There is more information here: https://makandracards.com/makandra/35133-how-to-split-config-routes-rb-in-rails-4 Pay attention that if in your original routes your code was under scope your new routs file also need to have that scope

Comment: This solution doesn't seems to work when you have concerns defined and reference them from one route file to another.

Answer (score 10):

[Here's a nice article, simple, concise, straight to the point](https://redgreen.no/2017/01/03/split-your-rails-routes.html) - not mine.

> config/application.rb
>
> ```
> module YourProject
>   class Application < Rails::Application
>     config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/routes)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> config/routes/admin_routes.rb
>
> ```
> module AdminRoutes
>   def self.extended(router)
>     router.instance_exec do
>       namespace :admin do
>         resources :articles
>         root to: "dashboard#index"
>       end
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> config/routes.rb
>
> ```
>   Rails.application.routes.draw do
>     extend AdminRoutes
>
>     # A lot of routes
>   end
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution and it the rails will auto reload when changing the routes file?

Comment: Rails seems offer an official way for such a case which looks easier.
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#breaking-up-very-large-route-file-into-multiple-small-ones

Comment: @MitsutoshiWatanabe The `draw` approach is only available in Rails 6.1 and later

Answer (score 5):

I like the method demonstrated in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dhh/2492118) and expanded on in [this blog post](https://mattboldt.com/separate-rails-route-files/):

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def draw(routes_name)
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/routes/#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
end

BCX::Application.routes.draw do
  draw :api
  draw :account
  draw :session
  draw :people_and_groups
  draw :projects
  draw :calendars
  draw :legacy_slugs
  draw :ensembles_and_buckets
  draw :globals
  draw :monitoring
  draw :mail_attachments
  draw :message_preview
  draw :misc

  root to: 'projects#index'
end
```

Comment: We've been using this for quite some time but unfortunately it does not auto-reload the routes and you'll have to start/stop the server