# Is there a way to create a central routing file which contains only routes and the functions they are for in Rocket?

Tags: routes, rust, rust-rocket

Looking at [the example code](https://rocket.rs/guide/overview/#routing), they all define routes above the functions for handling them. For a bigger project this doesn't seem like it will scale.

Is there a way to create a central routing file which contains only the routes and the functions they are for similar to routes.rb in Rails?

Here is an example of a section of the routing file [from the GitLab Rails app](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6c51e220ef2774447038a909c4f22ff90eb624fb/config/routes.rb#L26-L37):

```rb
# Autocomplete
get '/autocomplete/users' => 'autocomplete#users'
get '/autocomplete/users/:id' => 'autocomplete#user'
get '/autocomplete/projects' => 'autocomplete#projects'
get '/autocomplete/award_emojis' => 'autocomplete#award_emojis'

# Search
get 'search' => 'search#show'
get 'search/autocomplete' => 'search#autocomplete', as: :search_autocomplete

# JSON Web Token
get 'jwt/auth' => 'jwt#auth'
```

This allows you to easily see which routes exist within the app without having to look throughout the project.

Comment: *this doesn't seem like it will scale* — why don't you try it and find out if it scales? [People ask how to split apart a routes.rb file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35609059/155423) when it gets too big. Even your GitLab example [splits it into multiple files](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/config/routes).

Comment: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.3.11/examples/manual_routes/src/main.rs