# Rails 5: Encapsulating route files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm refactoring my companies routes file following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609059/divide-large-routes-rb-to-multiple-files-in-rails-5) to look like the following.

config/application.rb

`module YourProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/routes)
  end
end`

config/routes/admin_routes.rb

`module AdminRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      namespace :admin do
        resources :articles
        root to: "dashboard#index"
      end
    end
  end
end`

config/routes.rb

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
    extend AdminRoutes
end`

However much of our newer RoR code we put into `appsules`, which are self contained little pieces of the application that contain their own controllers, models, serializers, etc, and someone mentioned how nice it would be if they also contained their own routes. The path to that would look like the following

`/appsules/#{appsule_name}/routes.rb`

But when I look at the `config.paths` in my application.rb I don't see any paths pertaining to the appsules directory. Is this possible to read in routes files in that fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Are you updating the autoload path to use the new folder structures? Something like:

```
module YourProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/config/routes
      #{config.root}/appsules/appsule1_name/routes.rb
      #{config.root}/appsules/appsule2_name/routes.rb
    )
  end
end
```

If you want them added dynamically, you should be able to iterate the `appsule` directory and add these files dynamically to the autoload path.

Comment: Yes I am doing that, and it works great for the general use case, but I get a name error if I just add the autoload path and try to include the module defined in the appsule routes file.

Comment: I should probably mention appsules is a gem https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/appsules/1.0.0

Comment: Ended up with some slightly different name spacing. One question, is it bad to put lots of stuff in the autoload_paths? I.E. if I add all 30 or so appsules to be autoloaded will my environment take lots longer to load?