# Automatically generating scoped and unscoped Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

We have a tenant-like application that specifies many tenant and general routes for the same controller/action. As an example:

```
get '/:subdomain/posts', to: 'posts#index'
get '/posts', to: 'posts#index'
```

As you can imagine, this gets cumbersome when many routes share this behaviour. I'm trying to design a module that can be included in the routes file that would let me specify routes like so:

```
general_and_tenant_scope do
  resources :posts
  resources :users
end
```

And have it automatically map to something like this:

```
scope '/:subdomain', as: :tenant do
  resources :posts
  resources :users
end

resources :posts
resources :users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a helper like so:

```
def general_and_tenant_scope(&block)
  scope('/:subdomain', as: :tenant, &block)

  yield
end
```

You may be able to include this as a helper by employing a technique outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609059/divide-large-routes-rb-to-multiple-files-in-rails-5), but we simply put this at the top of our `routes.rb`.

Comment: @Alex I think it is to generate both scoped and unscoped routes.  If there's a more concise approach please let me know!