# how to handle observers in rails 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, observers

In my application.rb , I have this code snippet:

```
  _observers  = Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/observers/*"].map{ |path| "observers/#{Pathname.new(path).basename.to_s.split(".").first}" }
config.mongoid.observers =  _observers
```

I updated rails version from 3.2.22 to 4.0.0,

Now I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `observers=' for Mongoid::Config:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Are you actually using any observers in your app? If not you can just remove the line. Observers where one of those things that where hyped for a short time but turned out to be a not so great idea and where removed in Rails 4. Otherwise you will have to find an alternatives to whatever services the observers are providing or a use gem which provides hooks for Rails 3 style observers.

Comment: @max ..if i am removing this line , I am getting this error application.rb:47:in `block in <class:Application>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @max at line 47 i have this code snippet:                                               Dir["#{config.root}/config/routes/*"].each do |route_file|
        config.paths['config/routes'] << route_file
    end

Comment: Thats totally unrelated to observers, its a hacky way to load the routes from a bunch of files in `/config/routes`. It will not work in Rails 4. I would suggest you merge the routes to a single file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844813/rails-4-split-routes-rb-into-multiple-smaller-files

Comment: Is this a legacy application that you have taken over and are trying to update?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile` add the following:

```
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'mongoid-observers'
```