# Is it possible to include external routes files into the main routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a large number of routes that I would like to separate into different route files.

I created a "routes-secondary.rb" and added some routes there. I then tried to add something like this in the app's main routes.rb:

> require "#{Rails.root}/config/routes-secondary.rb"

That does not work however because Rails doesn't recognize the routes in routes-secondary.rb. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I've updated this answer to take advantage of the RouteReloader for development work)

You can easily accomplish this (even in Rails 4!).

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :foo
end
```

config/routes/included.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bar
end
```

config/initializers/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes_reloader.paths.unshift *Dir[File.expand_path("../../routes/**/*.rb", __FILE__)]
```

This will add all files under config/routes to the application routes, and it'll probably add them in reverse lexical order by filename. If you want to load the routes in a different order, rather than the glob, you can just push or unshift the routes onto routes_reloader.paths in the order desired.

rake routes:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
foo_index GET    /foo(.:format)          foo#index
          POST   /foo(.:format)          foo#create
  new_foo GET    /foo/new(.:format)      foo#new
 edit_foo GET    /foo/:id/edit(.:format) foo#edit
      foo GET    /foo/:id(.:format)      foo#show
          PATCH  /foo/:id(.:format)      foo#update
          PUT    /foo/:id(.:format)      foo#update
          DELETE /foo/:id(.:format)      foo#destroy
bar_index GET    /bar(.:format)          bar#index
          POST   /bar(.:format)          bar#create
  new_bar GET    /bar/new(.:format)      bar#new
 edit_bar GET    /bar/:id/edit(.:format) bar#edit
      bar GET    /bar/:id(.:format)      bar#show
          PATCH  /bar/:id(.:format)      bar#update
          PUT    /bar/:id(.:format)      bar#update
          DELETE /bar/:id(.:format)      bar#destroy
```

Comment: This looks great. Thank you Chris. The external routes works as expected. One issue I ran into is that if I modify the main routes.rb file in any way (eg adding a comment or even a space), the routes in the external file stops working, which forces me to restart the app. Do you know what's causing that issue?

Comment: I would be suspicious of the routes reloading mechanism in Rails 4. I haven't encountered that since my routes have been mostly static since working with Rails 4. Give me a few to see if I can get my head around what it's doing.

Comment: @sjsc See my edit; that patches the extra route files into the routes reloader, which makes it all work as expected in development. It's the same mechanism that engines use for adding their routes to an app.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried it by adding the unshift line you had above but got this error: "RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array"

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? I'm testing with a 4.1.8 app.

Comment: Hi Chris. I finally got my 4.1.8 upgrade to work. I'm still getting an "`unshift': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)" error however.

Comment: Are you modifying those routes in an initializer? My test case there is definitely working with a stock 4.1.8 app. It's possible those get frozen after initialization or something, though.

Comment: Hi Chris. I'll definitely play around with it. I'm sure it's just some part of my code that's messing up everything since the stock 4.1.8 app works fine. I appreciate your help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4, you cannot do this out of the box and it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844813/rails-4-split-routes-rb-into-multiple-smaller-files). In rails 3, you can modify your config.paths hash as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303660/splitting-routes-file-into-multiple-files).

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you Mike. I'm using Rails 4 unfortunately